# How to add a legend for each kdeplot in a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, kdeplot

I am having little difficulty adding legend to a CDF plot with seaborn.

#### Imports and sample data

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.plyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

X = np.random.randn(20,1,10,4)
k = X[:,0,:,0].reshape(-1)
l  = X[:,0,:,1].reshape(-1)
m  = X[:,0,:,2].reshape(-1)
n  = X[:,0,:,3].reshape(-1)
```

#### Example 1

```
plt.figure()
plt.title('Some Distribution ')
plt.ylabel('CDF')
plt.xlabel('x-labelled)')
sns.kdeplot(k,cumulative=True, legend=True)
sns.kdeplot(l,cumulative=True, legend=True)
sns.kdeplot(m,cumulative=True, legend=True)
sns.kdeplot(n,cumulative=True, legend=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Example 2

```
plt.figure()
plt.title('Some Distribution ')
plt.ylabel('CDF')
plt.xlabel('x-labelled)')
sns.kdeplot(k,cumulative=True)
sns.kdeplot(l,cumulative=True)
sns.kdeplot(m,cumulative=True)
sns.kdeplot(n,cumulative=True)
plt.legend(labels=['legend1', 'legend2', 'legend3', 'legend4'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Tested in `seaborn v0.12.0`: **Example 2** produces a legend, as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`legend = True` is the default in `seaborn.kdeplot`, so you have no need to specify it. However, what you do need to specify is the labels.

```
sns.kdeplot(k,cumulative=True, label = 'a')
sns.kdeplot(l,cumulative=True, label = 'b')
sns.kdeplot(m,cumulative=True, label = 'c')
sns.kdeplot(n,cumulative=True, label = 'd')
```

Outputs:

[image]

Even in your second example, with `plt.legend(labels=['legend1', 'legend2', 'legend3', 'legend4'])`, you need to first specify labels in `seaborn.kdeplot()`. If you pass different labels in `plt.legend()` the labels passed to `searbon.kdeplot()` will be replaced, but if no labels are passed to seaborn, I get the same output as you (i.e. no legend at all).

Example:

```
sns.kdeplot(k,cumulative=True, label = 'a')
sns.kdeplot(l,cumulative=True, label = 'b')
sns.kdeplot(m,cumulative=True, label = 'c')
sns.kdeplot(n,cumulative=True, label = 'd')
plt.legend(labels = ['1','2','3','4'])
```

Outputs:

[image]